# Bootstrap Carousel not working properly

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, carousel

I made a website on bootstrap platform and I am having problems with the top carousel. After a loop of 3 or 4, it disrupts and looks really ugly. Can anyone help me with this issue. Please check http://www.technotrendsolutions.com for reference.

Comment: Show the code you implemented

Comment: @Java_User , Give it 3-4 minutes. It will disrupt. It is happening in Mozilla.

Comment: @xK0nB1n , The code is to big to fit in the comments. Can I mail you the code ?

Comment: @RedforgeInnovatives It's been opened for at least 8 mins though I'm using Chrome. Is it something that is happening in Mozilla alone?

Comment: @xk0nB1n, I guess its only happening in Mozilla. And if I keep it open for long, the green background vanishes.

Comment: @RedforgeInnovatives ofCourse Yes.. can u see my mail Id. I don't think stackoverFlow have some terms on sharing some code personally.

Comment: @RedforgeInnovatives Or you can make a fiddle. choose either of way you want. We all are here to help.

Answer (score 0):

The  `background-position` horizontal value in the `da-slider` is growing up without control with every loop. After 5 mins its value is about `15000%`